# spring boot error - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not configure JTA platform

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

```
**I am using Java 6/Spring Framework 4.1.4/Spring Boot v1.2.1.RELEASE and Hibernate 3.5.
```

Since I am on Java6, I use embedded Tomcat 7.0.59
    Why is it trying JTA (or how can I suppress the ComponentScan)?
    What does this error mean and how to resolve it?
    I have tried to use individual annotations instead of SpringBootApplication and have same error.
    I am trying to use Spring boot to create a service and then use the Import Resource to load the HB connections etc.**

my application.properties:

```
server.port=2003
debug=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@***
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect**
```

My Gradle snippet is:

```
compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:${springSecurityVersion}"
compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:${springSecurityVersion}"
compile "org.springframework:spring-context:${springVersion}"
compile "org.springframework:spring-web:${springVersion}"
compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:${springVersion}"
compile "org.springframework:spring-jms:${springVersion}"
compile "org.springframework:spring-orm:${springVersion}"
compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:${springVersion}"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}"
```

code:

```
package com.mine.apps.force;
import com.mine.common.ErrorLog;    
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.mine")
//@ImportResource("classpath:webserver/forceAppContext.xml")
@RequestMapping(value="/force")
public class forceMicroService
{   
    private static ErrorLog logger = new ErrorLog("forceMicroService");

      public forceMicroService()
      {
      }


      @RequestMapping(value="/retry/{Id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
      @ResponseBody
      String sendToforce(@PathVariable("Id") String Id)
      {
          String func = "sendToforce";

          logger.Info(func, "Entering");
          return Id;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
          SpringApplication.run(forceMicroService.class, args);
    }
}
```

stack trace is

> ```
> 10:06:11,443 WARN  [embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext]: Exception
> ```
>
> encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]:
>   Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not configure JTA
>   platform
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>               at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
>               at com.vzw.etm.apps.enforce.EnforceMicroService.main(EnforceMicroService.java:47)
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]:
>   Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not configure JTA
>   platform
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
>               ... 17 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not configure JTA platform
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.getNoJtaPlatformManager(HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.java:151)
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.configureJtaPlatform(HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.java:129)
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.customizeVendorProperties(HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.java:99)
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:111)
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6ecd1b06.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$6()
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6ecd1b06$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$797c76e5.invoke()
>               at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>               at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
>               at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6ecd1b06.entityManagerFactory()
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>               ... 18 more
>       10:06:11,465 INFO  [concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor]: Shutting down ExecutorService 'metricsExecutor'
>       Jan 12, 2016 10:06:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
>       INFO: Stopping service Tomcat

Comment: PLease give some context of what you try to do...

Comment: I am trying to create a service using Boot/Tomcat.  Sprign seems to do a auto scan and is trying JPA connection. The real logic is in the context xml that i have in the code (commented out).

Comment: basically take the existing code and convert them into a Boot based service.  the code base is a mix of JDBC/Hibernate/SOAP services and REST services.  So the intent is to take some of the non-WS based calls and convert them into a service

Comment: Will your service be deployed as executable JAR with embedded Tomcat or will you deploy it in an application server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot does not support Hibernate 3.5.
Minimum required version is Hibernate 4.2.

You can work around that by completely disabling the auto configuration for Hibernate:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

If you do deploy your service as an executable JAR with embedded Tomcat, there is no reason to use such an old Hibernate version, so you should use the one which Spring Boot defines.

Comment: it worked.  Thanks a lot.  This opens a new question on where should I apply Spring Boot.

Comment: In addition to this bean I also had to exclude `JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class` to make it work.